# Can firebase run 100% offline and sync up later?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I need to build an application for mission work that runs 100% offline and then syncs up with the server when it reconnects to the internet. The application "currently" has over 6k people in the database that needs to be searchable when the missionaries are in the field. The challenge is that I need "all" of the data local and disconnected on multiple laptops or tablets. I know I can use a database like CouchDB but I would much prefer use firebase or something similar to keep the management of the system simple. Is this possible with [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-29-announcing-mobile-offline-support.html and https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html

Comment: Let me know if my answered work for you. If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Comment: I'm wondering if Frank or David or anyone at Google/Firebase is at liberty to discuss whether or not a Web version of offline functionality is in the works and if so is there a timeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web client can handle intermittent offline (will work offline, but won't survive a page refresh), but not persistent offline like the native SDKs can.

If your web app needs specific offline functionality, look into using [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) and [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB). You can create a persistent offline cache of data for offlne functionality.

[Jake Archibald's Offline Cookbook](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/) is a great resource for building offline web apps.